# Changing the RDS certificate in Server 2012 R2 while users are logged-in

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, rdp, rds

Is it possible to update the certificate used by Remote Desktop Services on Windows Server 2012 R2 while users are connected in RDP without disconnecting every one ?
I think that it will be transparent for the existing connections, and that the new certificate will be used for new connections but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Active users will use previous certificate until they reconnect or security transport re-negotiation occurs. In this case certificate change will be transparent for users.